# Return matched elements' attribute ar array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery, it is easy to select elements as array.

> $("a");  // return as elements array of anchors

But is it possible to select **matched elements' attributes** as array?

Currently I need to do something like...

> links = [ ];
>
> $("a").each(function() {
>
> ```
> href = $(this).attr("href");
> links.push(href);
> ```
>
> });

Are there any better method to fill the variable **links** with href of the all matched anchors?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use $.map like so:

```
var links = $('a').map(function() { return this.href }).get()
```

Comment: +1 - You'll need a `.get()` on the end, but this is the correct approach.

Comment: Ah thanks, I just quickly did `[0]` and assumed it was an array when it was in fact a jquery constructed array-like object.

Comment: This seems a bit verbose for a library whose purpose seems to be masking these kind of gymnastics from the programmer. Why doesn't this simply return an array: var links = $('a').attr('href'); Wouldn't that be cleaner and more readable? (consider this my suggestion for the next iteration of jQuery...)

Comment: What about "data" attributes ?

Answer (score 5):

```
var links = $("a").map(function(){return $(this).attr("href")}).get();
```

Comment: This approach works great for custom defined ``data`` attributes like ``data-id``, ``data-name`` etc.